# How to prevent `fmt` shell script from adding double space after end of sentences?

Tags: macos, shell

I use the `fmt` shell script for line wrapping in several editors of Mac OS X. I'm generally satisfied with it, except one thing—double space after end of sentence. (These days few people do that, right? That seems really old schooled, at least to me, and wastes the precious space of eighty columns.)

I know there's a `-d chars` option for `fmt` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/fmt.1.html)) which specifies the sentence-ending sentinels, so currently I trick the script by `-d @`, noting that `@` seldom enters the scope. It works, but I guess there are some better solutions rather than this tricky one? Is it possible to set `chars` following the `-d` to a real empty list?

Comment: A minor point: `fmt` is an executable, not a shell script.

Comment: @KeithThompson Oh sorry I messed them up... `fmt` can be used in shell scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d ''` works for me:

```
fmt -d '' <<< $'Do not.\nDouble-space.'
```

Comment: it's funny, why does this option doesn't exist in Linux?